# Switch в Spinner

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Здравствуйте, в общем добавил spinner в mainactivity(выбор этажей:1 этаж, 2 этаж). 
Нужно было сделать так чтобы при выборе 1 этажа в списке были комнаты 1 этажа, при выборе 2го комнаты 2 го этажа. Это я выполнил(см в MainActivity). Теперь нужно сделать чтобы при нажатии комнат их переводили в соответствующие activity. Я это пытался реализовать, но где то я ошибся. Дело в том что при нажатии на комнаты второго этажа открываются активити комнат первого этажа. Я так понял я неправильно сделал функцию switch в спиннере, там я в начале функции очищаю лист RecycleView с помошью albumList.clear(). И поэтому значения case-ов сбивается. Это лишь мое предположение. Правильного решения не нашел, помогите пожалуйста

Mainactivity.java:

```
 albumList = new ArrayList<>();
        adapter = new RoomsAdapter(this, albumList);

        RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(this, 1);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
        recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                value = parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
                switch (position) {
                    case 0:
                        firstLevel();
                        break;

                    case 1:
                        secondLevel();
                        break;
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

            }
        });


   ...


private void firstLevel() {
        int[] first = new int[]{
                R.drawable.reg,
                R.drawable.spec,
                R.drawable.ozd,
                R.drawable.mast};

        albumList.clear();

        Album a = new Album("Кафедра", first[0]);
        albumList.add(a);

        a = new Album("Зал", first[1]);
        albumList.add(a);

        a = new Album("Оздоровительный зал", first[2]);
        albumList.add(a);

        a = new Album("Школа мастеров", first[3]);
        albumList.add(a);

        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
    private void secondLevel() {
        int[] second = new int[]{
                R.drawable.prez,
                R.drawable.nemec,
                R.drawable.chitzal,
                R.drawable.centr};

        albumList.clear();

        Album b = new Album("Читальный зал библиотеки первого Президента", second[0]);
        albumList.add(b);

        b = new Album("Немецко-французский читальный зал", second[1]);
        albumList.add(b);

        b = new Album("Читальный зал", second[2]);
        albumList.add(b);

        b = new Album("Центр по изучению нового языка ", second[3]);
        albumList.add(b);

        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

RoomsAdapter.java:

```
public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public TextView title;
    public ImageView thumbnail;

    public MyViewHolder(View view) {
        super(view);
        title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.title);
        thumbnail = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.thumbnail);
        thumbnail.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                switch (getAdapterPosition()){
                    case 0:
                        Intent regintent = new Intent(mContext, Register.class);
                        mContext.startActivity(regintent);
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        Intent specintent = new Intent(mContext, Spec.class);
                        mContext.startActivity(specintent);
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        Intent ozdintent = new Intent(mContext, Ozd.class);
                        mContext.startActivity(ozdintent);
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        Intent mastintent = new Intent(mContext, Mast.class);
                        mContext.startActivity(mastintent);
                        break;
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Album.java:

```
public class Album {
    private String name;
    private int numOfSongs;
    private int thumbnail;

    public Album() {
    }

    public Album(String name, int thumbnail) {
        this.name = name;
        this.thumbnail = thumbnail;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getThumbnail() {
        return thumbnail;
    }

    public void setThumbnail(int thumbnail) {
        this.thumbnail = thumbnail;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

В коде у вас ошибок нет. У вас ошибки в логике и понимании. Постараюсь объяснить.

Для достижения нужного поведения, вам необходимо иметь тип ячейки, чтоб понять в какую активити переходить, а вы обрабатываете позицию в списке. Те получается сколько вы не делали бы разных комнат, вы всегда будете переходить в зависимости от позиции. И действительно это лего исправить, я не знаю вашей внутренней реализации и напишу простой код с наименшим кол-ом изменений, в идеале я бы всё переписал:

в классе `Album` добавим переменную, напирмер:
int levelNumber, примерно так:

```
public class Album {

private int levelNumber;
private String roomName;
private int roomResImage;

public Album(int levelNumber, String roomName, int roomResImage) {
    this.levelNumber = levelNumber;
    this.roomName = roomName;
    this.roomResImage = roomResImage;
}

public int getLevelNumber() {
    return levelNumber;
}

public void setLevelNumber(int levelNumber) {
    this.levelNumber = levelNumber;
}

public String getRoomName() {
    return roomName;
}

public void setRoomName(String roomName) {
    this.roomName = roomName;
}

public int getRoomResImage() {
    return roomResImage;
}

public void setRoomResImage(int roomResImage) {
    this.roomResImage = roomResImage;
}
```

}

тогда в адаптере примерно будет так:

```
public TextView title;
public ImageView thumbnail;

public MyViewHolder(View view) {
    super(view);

    title = view.findViewById(R.id.title);
    thumbnail = view.findViewById(R.id.thumbnail);

    int  levelNumber = albums.get(getAdapterPosition()).getLevelNumber();

    thumbnail.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            switch (levelNumber){

                case 1: break; // переход на 1-й левел
                case 2: break; // переход на 2-й левел
                ...
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: я маленько не понял, а какое это значение будет иметь к активити? ведь мы задали только этажи? Для ясности добавил Album.java

Comment: Нужно сделать так, чтобы каждая из комнат переводила в разные активити(каждая комната - своя активити)

Comment: Spinner этажей реализован в MainActivity(в тулбаре), а переход по активити комнат в RoomsAdapter

Comment: Спинер здесь ваще не имеет никакого отношения, вы просто при смене позиции, меняете данные, а переходы обрабатываются по старому в адаптере. Делать +100500 активити для каждой комнаты, очень сомнительно, но даже если вы уже решили так делать, замените переменную левел на уникальный номер комнаты и будет вам счастье. Да и поможет вам Тот

Comment: А как можно реализовать переходы не  создавая активити?(что то подобное новой страницы). И что вы имели ввиду под "Тот"?